# Sending multiple syslog entries in one message

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using python to send syslog logs to a remote server based on existing files. The syslog is using TCP and not UDP and therefore I suspect that sending multiple files with 20,000 lines, line by line, is slower than if I could send it in one message. However appending \r for each log doesn't seem to work. Is there any option to achieve it?

Comment: syslog is designed to send only single messages. It should be possible to define a template which sends multiple logs as one message. If you need help, please share your code and/or update your question.